# PyGame not rendering shapes?

Tags: python, render, draw, pygame, rect

I have made the following code to render the map using tiles, it loops through the file and translates letters into tiles (rectangles);

```
currtile_x = 0
currtile_y = 0
singlerun = 1

if singlerun == 1:
    singlerun = 0
    with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
                for character in line:
                    if character == "\n":
                        currtile_y += 10
                    else:
                        if character == "x":
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (1,2,3), (currtile_x, currtile_y, 10, 10), 0)
                            currtile_x += 10
                        else: 
                            if character == "a":
                                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,255), (currtile_x, currtile_y, 10, 10), 0)
                                currtile_x += 10
```

Here is the townhall.map file:

```
xxxxx
xaaax
xaaax
xaaax
xxxxx
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well when event loop code is added to it. Since you haven't posted the whole program, everything I can do is to post a working program that contains your code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

currtile_x = 0
currtile_y = 0
with open('townhall.map') as f:
    for line in f:
        for character in line:
            if character == '\n':
                currtile_y += 10
                currtile_x = 0
            elif character == 'x':
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (currtile_x, currtile_y, 10, 10), 0)
                currtile_x += 10
            elif character == 'a':
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,255), (currtile_x, currtile_y, 10, 10), 0)
                currtile_x += 10

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @pixelgeer: There are a few problems with that code... But the most obvious one is that the map (rectangles) is rendered once, and then the background and other things are painted over it each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, but what other problems are there?

Comment: @pixelgeer: Nothing critical, but the programming style isn't very good. For example, instead of using 4 variables and 16 `if`s for direction, you could use some `dict`s or classes... Lines 26-37 do nothing useful (you probably know that). It is unusual to make multiple event loops; most people make one loop and depending on game state call different functions.